# How to add custom languages in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Is it possible to add custom language in sitecore like English(California) just like we have English(Texas)?

[image]

If yes, please let me know how to can we add.

Comment: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4297/how-to-add-custom-lang-region-in-sitecore-system-language

Comment: I tried that. It worked only for English(Texas) but didn't work for English(California).